# find the least upper and the greatest lower bounds of the given set of real number?

Tags: real-analysis

let $n  \ge3 $   be an arbitrarily fixed integer. Take all the possible finite sequences $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of positive numbers. Find the least upper and  the greatest lower bounds of the set of real numbers

$\sum_ {k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{a_{k } + a_{k+1} +a_{k+2}}$ where put $a_{n+1} =a_1 $and $a_{n+2} =a_2$

my ideas: I take  $ a_k = x^k$ where $k>0$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{a_{k } + a_{k+1} +a_{k+2}}=$ $\frac {x}{x+x^2+x^3} +\cdots + \frac{x^{n-2}} {x^{n-2} +x^{n-1} +x^n} +\cdots +\frac{x^n}{x^n+x+x^2}$,

here I don't know how to proceed further.

Anybody please help me....I would be more thankful

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are two things to do here: 
1) Find a way to make the sum large.
2) Find a way to make the sum small.

In general, it's good to check extreme cases. What happens if you set all the $a_i$ to be equal? What if you set some of them very close to $0$?

Comment: You had a misplaced dollar sign. My edit was merely to fix that.